# Default url set in springboot application by using artifact id

Tags: maven, spring-boot

when I am using spring boot in my web project login page is coming directly after http://localhost:8080/login#/ but I want it as a http://localhost:8080/demo/login#/ and here demo is artifact id name. That was hipping in my previous project but after using spring boot project I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties try:

```
server.contextPath=/${project.artifactId}/login
```

Then use maven filtering to inject the project.artifactId value into your contextPath property:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```